# User has no attribute get using inlineformset_factory

Tags: django

I am trying to add a One to Many relationship. Let's say student, class. My student model is giving me `no attribute get error`. The line before that says `return data.get(name)` Not very sure what is it trying to do.

forms.py

```
class StudentKlassForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Student
        fields = ['name']
StudentKlassFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Klass, Student, form = StudentKlassForm, extra=1)
```

view.py ... add a new student

```
student = Student.objects.get(id = student_id )
klass = Klass.objects.get(id = class_id)
form = StudentClassFormSet(student, instance = klass)
```

model.py
class Student

```
klass = models.ForeignKey(Klass)
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to have a variable named `class`: that's overloading terms and python doesn't like it. There will be unpredictable behavior when you do that.

Generally in these situations, I rename the variable `class` to `klass`.